# Google Script Date February 1 as February 32

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google script that automatically enters today's date in a particular column if data in other columns are edited. It works great, but I found out today "February 1" is coming in as "February 32". Here is my code below:

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  var sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetName();

  //range to edit
  var editRange = { // K:AB
    left : 11,
    right : 28
  };

  // Exit if we're out of range
  if (r.getColumn() < editRange.left || r.getColumn() > editRange.right) return;

  //Perform if on sheets if it ends in "15" "16" or "Old"/"old"
  if(sheetName.indexOf("15")>-1 || sheetName.indexOf("16")>-1 || sheetName.indexOf("Old")>-1 || sheetName.indexOf("old")>-1){
    if( r.getColumn() != 2) { //checks the column
      var row = r.getRow();
      var time = new Date();
      time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "MST", "DDMMMYYYY");
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C' + row.toString()).setValue(time);
    }
  };
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the [date format docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), uppercase "D" is the day in the year, not the day in the month. For that, use lowercase "d".

Comment: Interesting. I was using 'DD' all throughout the end of last year and it was working great. But I changed it to 'dd' and at least for February 1st it looks like it's working well. Thanks.